# Why does sub replace only one character with a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to strip all non-digit characters from a string. 
`/\D/` is a non-digit character (`[^0-9]`):

```
irb(main):010:0> s = "(123) 456-7890"
=> "(123) 456-7890"
irb(main):011:0> s.sub( /\D*/, '' )
=> "123) 456-7890"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sub` replaces once. `gsub` replaces all.

Answer (score 5):

Do as below using [`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-tr) or [`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
s.gsub(/[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]/ ,'')
# => "1234567890" 
s.tr('^0-9','') # even more faster
# => "1234567890"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use gsub instead:

```
 s.gsub( /\D/, '' )
```